# iOS xml parsing for media: content by NSXML

Tags: iphone, xml, image

I am not able to parse media content tag in below rss

http://news.yahoo.com/rss/

tried this......

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"])   
{
    NSString *imgURL=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
    NSLog(@"imgURL %@",imgURL);
}
```

Comment: have you searched for "media:thumbnail" this term in rss there were no tag regarding this.

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper check yahoo rss url

Comment: Did you ever get that figured out?